# Import from MS SQL Server to MS Access via ODBC lost all indexes

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I use SQL Server 2014 / 2017 (either expression version), I tried to move data from the SQL Server database to MS Access for some reasons, but what I face now, all indexes that created on each field in each table in SQL Server are not transferred to MS Access (2016).

Currently, the workaround is: I have to go to the tables that I need to set flag: index as example:

[image]

Is there any solution that can keep all indexes from SQL Server to Access?

Comment: You are doing the correct thing, just re-create the indexes in Access.This is not a problem. It may help to get a list of indexes from SQL server

Comment: The "why" will depend upon how it was that you did the "import" but most tools that just do a basic table copy only copy the column definitions and data, not the indexes, constraints, or other objects. You're best off creating the schema in the target database and then copying the data.

Comment: Why are you importing the data and not using a Linked Table?

Comment: @alroc, I have a reason / it's business part that need to do so. And link tables, I also face the same problem (slow)

Comment: And I can confirm that `Link tables` (via ODBC) if you check design view in MS Access, it also shows flag on `index: No` too.

Comment: @Osify - I do not see the behaviour you describe for linked tables. If I link a SQL Server table in Access I see the indexes for the Access linked table in Design View. However, tables *imported* into Access do not bring their indexes with them, not even the primary key. :(

Comment: The import, or transfer database command(s) do not  bring in the PK and all of the indexes. However, in the nav pane, a right click and convert to local table DOES bring in all the PK, and the indexes. So, code below can be used to import with PK and all the indexes active.

Answer (score 2):

You can at least get the PK and index(s) to come down from SQL server.

There are two ways to do this.

From the GUI?

Simply link to the table in question (create a linked table to sql server).

Then in the nav pane, simply right click on the linked table and choose “convert to local table”.

The above will thus preserve the PK (and indexes). And for any other column that has an index, you find Access also preserves (creates) the index local for you also.

If you are using code?

Then, first create the linked table.

Then execute the covert to local table.

Eg this code:

```
Dim strCon        As String
strCon = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_TimeTest1").Connect

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", strCon, acTable, _
           "dbo.tblbooking", "tblBookingLocal2", False, True
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "tblBookingLocal2", True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertLinkedTableToLocal
```

In above, I just grabbed a “known” and existing connection string from another linked table to the same SQL database.